# Pandas GroupBy and CumSum on a column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data set which looks like the following

```
doc_created_month   doc_created_year    speciality      doc_id count
8                   2016                Acupuncturist   1           
2                   2017                Acupuncturist   1           
4                   2017                Acupuncturist   1           
4                   2017                Allergist       1           
5                   2018                Allergist       1           
10                  2018                Allergist       2
```

I want to group by the month, year and speciality and get cumulative sum on 'doc_id count' column.

These are the following I tried:

```
1) docProfileDf2.groupby(by=['speciality','doc_created_year','doc_created_month']).sum().groupby(level=[0]).cumsum()

2) docProfileDf2.groupby(['doc_created_month','doc_created_year','speciality'])['doc_id count'].apply(lambda x: x.cumsum())
```

None of them are returning the proper cumulative sum. 
Any Solution can help.

The expected output should be:

```
doc_created_month   doc_created_year    speciality          doc_id count
    8                   2016                Acupuncturist   1           
    2                   2017                Acupuncturist   2           
    4                   2017                Acupuncturist   3           
    4                   2017                Allergist       1           
    5                   2018                Allergist       2           
    10                  2018                Allergist       4
```

For each year, month and speciality I want the cumsum of 'doc_id count'

Comment: Try `docProfileDf2.groupby(['doc_created_month','doc_created_year','speciality'])['doc_id count'].cumsum()`

Comment: @MohitMotwani tried mate, it aint working, just returning the 'doc_id count' column directly with no changes.

Answer (score 0):

> Please note that I changed `doc_id count` to `doc_id_count`

You first call `groupby('speciality')` in order to group your data by that column. The second step is to call `apply()`. You'll then *apply* a function on each group. In this case we perform another `groupby` on the other required columns and further call `group.sum().cumsum()` to get the desired result.

```
from io import StringIO
import pandas as pd

data = """
doc_created_month   doc_created_year    speciality      doc_id_count
8                   2016                Acupuncturist   1           
2                   2017                Acupuncturist   1           
4                   2017                Acupuncturist   1           
4                   2017                Allergist       1           
5                   2018                Allergist       1           
10                  2018                Allergist       2   
"""

df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(data), sep='\s+')

(df.groupby('speciality')
    .apply(lambda df_: df_.groupby(['doc_created_year', 'doc_created_month'])
           .sum().cumsum())
)
```

which outputs:

```
                                                  doc_id_count
speciality    doc_created_year doc_created_month              
Acupuncturist 2016             8                             1
              2017             2                             2
                               4                             3
Allergist     2017             4                             1
              2018             5                             2
                               10                            4
```

Comment: could you check my question again, i have added an expected result. what your producing is cumsum of year and month and not  based on speciality.

Comment: @SriramArvindLakshmanakumar I've updated my answer. This should be what you wanted.

Answer (score 0):

It is Simple:

Solution is:

```
df.groupby(by=['speciality','doc_created_year','doc_created_month']).sum().groupby(level=[0]).cumsum()
```

i had to sum and groupby at speciality level.